# How can make an object orbit a sphere in a random direction?

Tags: mathematics, orbit

How can I move an object on a random orbital path around a sphere?

I've created some objects at an initial position that is essentially a random point on the sphere offset by some distance (say, 10.0).

Now I want to choose a random direction and have the object orbit the sphere in that direction. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Are you able to move the object in a non-random direction around the sphere? As in, is the problem selecting a random direction or having the object orbit a sphere?

Comment: I think your question can be answered with: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59298/walking-on-a-sphere or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40133/arbitrary-rotation-about-a-sphere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First generate a random 3D rotation matrix. Then for each frame compute a simple, boring rotation vector around the center (e.g `x = r*cos(k*t), y = r*sin(k*t), z = 0`), multiply it by the rotation matrix, add it to the center of the sphere, and you have a random orbit.

Comment: How can I generate a random rotation matrix? Thanks

Comment: Create two different, normal, random 3D vectors A and B. Compute C = AxB; C should be perpendicular to the plane defined by A and B. Now compute B' = AxC. A, B' and C should be orthonormal, so you can use them as the columns of a matrix and it will be a rotation matrix.